# Для чего нужен метод syncState() в ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android-sdk, android

Для чего нужен метод syncState() в ActionBarDrawerToggle , не понятно, без syncState() и так все работает?

Answer (score 1):

Метод сей точно нужен. Попробуйте его убрать и начать открывать/закрывать Drawer, поворачивать экран и тому подобное. В определённый момент всё пойдёт не так без этого метода.

Comment: Так официальный пример без этого метода, точнее тот метод находится не там где должен находится. Он находится в onCreate  а судя по документации    " Call syncState() from your Activity's onPostCreate to synchronize the indicator with the state of the linked DrawerLayout after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred. ' то есть, он должен быть в   onPostCreate. Тем более я вертел, закрывал, погружал в фон приложение, и ничего такого не заметил.

Comment: @semiromid, возможно, если задать иконке отображение программно в стрелку, например, то без вызова `syncState()` этот вызов не применится... Во всяком случае, я как-то наблюдал проблемы с дровером при отсутствии `syncState()` в `onPostCreate()`